# Binding radio button ngFor angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I want to rate a user from a list. I've tried to do it like this

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userList; let i = index">
    <form class="rate">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" (click)="rateModel.ratedId = user.userId; rateModel.rateValue = 5; rateuser(i);" [checked]="user.rate > 4" />
        <label for="star5" title="Excellent">5 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" (click)="rateModel.ratedId = user.userId; rateModel.rateValue = 4; rateuser(i);" [checked]="user.rate < 4.5 && user.rate > 3" />
        <label for="star4" title="Good">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" (click)="rateModel.ratedId = user.userId; rateModel.rateValue = 3; rateuser(i);" [checked]="user.rate < 3.5 && user.rate > 2" />
        <label for="star3" title="Fair">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" (click)="rateModel.ratedId = user.userId; rateModel.rateValue = 2; rateuser(i);" [checked]="user.rate < 2.5 && user.rate > 1" />
        <label for="star2" title="Bad">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" (click)="rateModel.ratedId = user.userId; rateModel.rateValue = 1; rateuser(i);" [checked]="user.rate < 1.5 && user.rate > 0" />
        <label for="star1" title="Very bad">1 star</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

I used `*i` just to check if the iteration really works by showing it on console. But it only sends the index value of 0. And it couldn't assign the userId based on the iteration, it holds the first userId value.
[image: The output of the list generated by ngFor is like this.]

Comment: what is `userList` and what does it comprise of?

Comment: @Sririam `userList` is a list of users from server. I want to rate them individually. And the problem is the `user.userId` holds only the first value of the user from the list.

Comment: Are you sure userList is an array? @Scados

Comment: Yes `userList` is an array. I can see the list of the users on the dashboard. @Sriram

Comment: Worth noting: the community is not just male here. Our female community members sometimes tell us that post language can accidentally reflect the assumption that they do not exist, and they can find that exclusionary. It is therefore much appreciated - by some men as well - if you can try to avoid male-specific greetings. Thanks!

Comment: I think if the iteration does not get passed you should check logging your `userList` to see if there is an intermittent object by chance because you say that only the first index value gets logged.

Comment: @Scados Could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker? I'm having trouble seeing the big picture here on what should happen in this piece of code :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular transforms the **"name"** attribute to **ng-name** where in the browser expects a `"name"` attribute in your radio button tag. You can do this by adding `"[attr.name]="`

**To achieve this, You need to declare like this:**

```
 <input type="radio" id="star5" [attr.name]="rate" name="rate" value="5" 
(click)="rateModel.ratedId = user.userId; rateModel.rateValue = 5; rateuser(i);"  
[checked]="user.rate > 4" />
```

Comment: I've tried that too @Sashi, but it won't work. Appreciated your effort.

Comment: Can you please show, what html is generated for the radio button and the issue you are facing with it?